# dell desktop - 'no wifi adaptor found' ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking

I just installed ubuntu 22.04 on a new desktop. Can't connect to my wifi network. I can ping the router but nothing else.

unfortunately, inxi -F returns 'command not found'

I noticed today that my other computer, running ubuntu 20.04, shows under wireless settings, the same message (i.e. 'no wifi adapter found') Right now I have a wired connection, but used to have a wireless one in an older release (18.04 ?) Leads me to think this may be a version-related thing.

Comment: Welcome to Ubuntu, nice of you to drop by. Since you didn't give us any infos about your hardware, we need to shed some light on it. Open a terminal and execute `inxi -F`. Copy that code (with mouse and right click) and paste it into your **question** (not the comments). -Then we might be able to help

Comment: I agree with @kanehekili: you need to provide some additional details here to help resolve your issue. If you don't want to install `inxi` you can use the `lshw` command instead. Also, it'd be useful to provide your Dell PC model, as that can help provide additional details/information. Thanks